# How do I access Google Map Maker Maps in the V3 API?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-api-2

I know in V2 of the API, i can just use setMapType(G_MAPMAKER_HYBRID_MAP) to call the Google Map Maker maps, but how do I get this in V3? I tried going through the documentation, but they just covered the basic map types (ROADMAP, SATELLITE, HYBRID and TERRAIN).

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Feature depreciated in V3.  But there's a workaround, that isn't supported and is not in term w/ Google Map agreement, take a look at this thread:

[Support Google Map Maker V3](http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=2349)